# Delay in Connecting with XMPP Server using Smack

Tags: android, smack

I have a connection delay that I cannot find explanations. Basically the connection to the local machine takes almost 1min in the Emulator and 20s+ on the physical device. I have tried everything I know and ended up with the code below. The time on device is now around 15s, but it is still a lot for just connecting.

Am not doing anything yet, just connecting.

Anyone with idea what I can do to optimize the delay?

```
class XMPPConnectionManager {
    companion object  {
        const val JABBER_DOMAIN = "localhost"
        const val JABBER_URL = "192.168.1.101"
        const val JABBER_RESOURCE = "Resource"
        const val JABBER_PORT = 5222
        const val CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 300
        const val REPLY_TIMEOUT = 30000L
    }


    private val conn: XMPPTCPConnection by lazy {
        val builder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
            .setXmppDomain(JidCreate.domainBareFrom(JABBER_DOMAIN))
            .setHostAddress(InetSocketAddress(JABBER_URL, JABBER_PORT).address)
            .setResource(JABBER_RESOURCE)
            .setCompressionEnabled(true)
            .setSendPresence(false)
            .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled) //TODO: Enable it
            //.enableDefaultDebugger()
            .setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)

        val connection = XMPPTCPConnection(builder.build())
        connection.replyTimeout = REPLY_TIMEOUT

        //auto reconnection
        val reconnectionManager = ReconnectionManager.getInstanceFor(connection)
        reconnectionManager.enableAutomaticReconnection()
        reconnectionManager.setReconnectionPolicy(ReconnectionManager.ReconnectionPolicy.RANDOM_INCREASING_DELAY)

        connection.connect()

        return@lazy connection
    }

    fun login(username: String?, password: String?): Boolean {
        try {
            if (!conn.isConnected) {
                conn.connect()
            }

            if(!conn.isAuthenticated){
                conn.login(username, password)
                //Setup OX-IM and other listeners
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used a desktop client like pigeon to verify this doesn't happen on other xmpp clients? Also smack has a Android Debugger - I think you can set a logger/ debugger factory on the configuration builder. I have used this library with multiple xmpp servers and never had issues like this. Also your connection time out seems low .. assuming it's 300milliseconds.

Comment: @MarkKeen have verified with Spark client and seems everything is OK. It have been a strange thing indeed. I lived with it with v4.3.4 and now with latest beta nothing have changed. I'm suspecting something is wrong with DNS but cannot just understand where exactly. I put tha low timeout to make sure that I optimize it to work to that constrain on localhost. I will raise it to reasonable value before production release!

Comment: how do you setup your connection/login?